# uninstalling typescript without node

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm having a lot of trouble with Typescript.  I installed the latest downloading it from their website and I'm trying to uninstall it in order to install an older version.  I'm running VS 2013 as well.  I've tried used npm when I installed nodejs, but I'm not sure if it's working.  I see in node_modules, it creates a folder called typescript when I install it.  When I try to uninstall, it will output unbuild typescript and some version number.  So I would think that that did the trick.  But then when I go to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.9
```

I see the tsc.exe is still there.  And then when I try

```
tsc -v
```

I see 0.9.7 is installed when I want to install an older version.  I have been googling for hours and I must not be looking in the right areas.  But how can I uninstall TS without using node since that doesn't seem to be working for me.  I uninstalled and reinstalled node to see if that did the trick, restarted the computer, restarted VS2013.  In VS2013 it will also allow me to create TS files even though I ran

```
npm uninstall typescript
```

So I'm not sure what's going on and where this stuff gets installed, but I'd like to remove it manually somehow.

Comment: Do you have the VS extension for TypeScript installed? It seems like you do given the location.

Comment: @WiredPrairie How can I check for the extension?  When I go to Extensions and Updates, I start typing "typ" and nothing comes up.  Is it preinstalled with VS2013?

Comment: It's in "Add/Remove" programs (or also known as "Uninstall or change a program") as it uses a full installer. Look for `TypeScript for Microsoft Visual Studio` ....

Comment: @WiredPrairie Ah I didn't know Microsoft installs VS add-ons there.  Can you put that in an answer so I can mark the quesiton answered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To uninstall the version of Typescript used by Visual Studio, use "add/remove programs" in Windows and remove "TypeScript for Visual Studio". It's installed as a program rather than an extension for VS (and as you've noticed, it doesn't use the NodeJs version).

Answer (score 3):

The visual studio version of TypeScript does *not* depend on nodejs. It uses IE for compilation.

You can uninstall the nodejs version using `npm uninstall -g typescript` if you installed it previously (which you probably didn't).

And then simply install TS from : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790

Comment: that was the initial link I used to install Typescript the first time.  I can't seem to remove that version of Typescript from my system.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: hehe i used the link only to downgrade my global tsc to 1.0.0 from 2.0.9