# How to completely uninstall all versions TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have tried:

```
npm uninstall typescript -g

choco uninstall typescript
```

as well as looking in Programs  for the visual studio uninstaller (which wasn't there), as mentioned here: [uninstalling typescript without node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393590/uninstalling-typescript-without-node)

I still have 2 directories (1.0 and 1.1) under Microsoft SDKs and I don't see any sort of uninstaller in there.

I am wondering what is the cleanest way to remove all installations of TypeScript from my system?

Comment: Which version[s] of Visual Studio (including Update versions) do you have installed?

Comment: I didn't install via VS extensions if that is what you are wondering BUT I am currently running VS 2010, VS 2013 and VS 14 CTP. Besides I want to start clean when I type tcs -v it shows the older version is being used. I could edit the environment variable but I prefer to work clean.

Comment: Version 1.0 is an integral part of VS2013, I doubt you'll want to uninstall the whole shebang.  This is an XY question, nobody knows why you think you need to do this.

Comment: Should I just rearrange the ENV variables to get 1.1 to get picked up?

Comment: Please describe your *actual* problem? Is it that `tsc` from the commandline is running a different version of TypeScript than you expect?

Comment: My original problem was that I wanted to uninstall typescript and start fresh but since it is apparently not uninstallable without removing visual studio my actual problem now is getting the 1.1 version to be used instead of the older one from the commandline.

Comment: @Hans fyi my main reason was because Chocolaty (i'm trying to use choocolaty more)wasn't picking it up when cup'd it and I also wanted to only have the latest version on my system. I also wanted to understand how it was installed on my system in the first place because I never specifically installed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript is built into both VS 2013 Update 2 the VS 14 CTP and cannot be separately uninstalled. You could uninstall both of those versions of Visual Studio if it is somehow critical to remove those folders.

Comment: So you think they were installed with my VS installations then? How do I go about setting 1.1 as the one to use?

Comment: "the one to use" where?

Comment: Using `msbuild`? `tsc.exe`? `grunt`? Something else?

Comment: oh gotcha just tsc from the command line. I'm guessing i should reorder the PATH or something so that it gets hit first?

Comment: Yep, change your PATH as needed. It should be fine to completely remove the 1.0 folder from PATH so there's no need to care about ordering

Answer (score 17):

You can now uninstall "TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015" from the Control Panel in Programs and Features. It was automatically installed with Visual Studio 2015 in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You might have an old TypeScript installation on your computer because of a Microsoft SDK:

```
cmd>tsc --version
Version 1.0.3.0
```

If you check the `PATH` environment variable, you may find an entry like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\
```

In my case, the uninstallation of "TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015" did not remove `tsc.exe` etc. from this path, probably because it was installed as part of the Windows 10 SDK or something else.

You can remove the entry from the `PATH` environment variable or at least move it below the entry for Node.js (probably `C:\Program Files\nodejs`) or nvm (like `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\nvm`) in case you use Node Version Manager. This will prevent that calls to `tsc` run the ancient TypeScript compiler:

```
cmd>tsc --version
Version 3.1.3
```

Don't forget to restart your command line after changes to environment variables for them to take effect!

If you are unsure what binary the `tsc` command will actually run then use the `where` command to find out:

```
cmd>where tsc
C:\Program Files\nodejs\tsc
C:\Program Files\nodejs\tsc.cmd
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\tsc.js
```

The priority is top to bottom. The first entry in my case is a (Linux) shell script and usually not executable on Windows. The second entry is a Windows Batch script and this is the one that will be executed. It basically invokes Node.js (simplified):

```
node.exe node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use nvm to manage multiple version node, **try `where tsc` to find out the bin path. Maybe it is installed in another version node directory.**